# Programming contest approach

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is broad question, but would like to know views of experts.
I came across one document [Suffix arrays – a contest approach](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=suffix%20array%20programming%20contest&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://algorithmics.comp.nus.edu.sg/wiki/_media/training/suff_ar_eng.pdf?id=training%253Aioi_workshop_2009&cache=cache&ei=Q7v8Tpv8FMjwrQeT0ZgB&usg=AFQjCNGd72U2H3hX80UDT_ZG2htVHtlL2A&cad=rja), also found some comments that participant should be ready with such data structures already in hand. now a days lot of online programming puzzles are coming with time bound. So I would like to know what are the other data-structures/algorithms should one be ready with.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for [codegolf.se]?

Answer (score 11):

I have been competing for about 10 years now and have created a not-so-bad library myself. Most of the really good competitors have their blogs for instance the legend [Petr Mitrichev](http://petr-mitrichev.blogspot.com) and there they explain ideas they got on some competitive problems. Reading these can help you - if you see a nice idea implement it and have it stored. 
I add algorithms to my library when I see a problem that involves them. That way I can verify that my implementation is correct- I only add an algorithm if I have passed at least one problem with its implementation.

Here is a list with some of the algorithms I have:

- I have a huge geometrial library with classes representing points, lines, polygons, segments, circles and some operations with them(for instance intersection, convex hull of set of points etc)
- Tarjan's [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for strongly connected components
- [Dinitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitz_blocking_flow_algorithm) flow algorithm
- Bipartite matching implementation
- Min cost max flow implementation
- [Aho-Corasic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) string searching algorithm
- [Knuth-morris-pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-morris-pratt) string searching algorithm
- [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin-Karp_string_search_algorithm) string searching algorithm
- Linear time suffix tree using ukonnen's [algorithm](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/dsaaj/enrich/c16/suffix.htm)
- Fast exponentiation
- Polynom implementation
- Big integer implementation
- Fractional numbers implementation
- Matrix class implementation
- Prime factorization
- [Eratosthenes Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes_Sieve)
- [Segment Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)
- [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)
- [2-Sat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability) algorithm. For this I use Tarjan's algorithm mentioned above.

You will notice that some of the most basic algorithms(like BFS,DFS, Dijkstra) are not mentioned above and that is because I don't have them implemented. These algorithms can not be easily generalized in a way that you will simply copy and paste them and everything will work. Also it takes me less then 5 minutes to write them - I usually put in my library only algorithms that are either hard to implement or are easy to make an error when implementing them.

Comment: what is your blog?

Comment: @x-rw Sorry, I don't have one! I never got too much into doing blogs

Answer (score 1):

Check out these [featured articles](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=features&d2=archive) @ TopCoder. They are really cool.

While you are at it, I suggest taking part in the programming contests at TopCoder. Because the best way to improve is to practice & keep taking part in such contests.

Also [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) too is really addictive.

Answer (score 0):

Also, take a look at the [Programming Challenges](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638) book, it's a great reference on the subject - it presents the topics necessary for succeeding in a programming contest, backed by an [online](http://www.programming-challenges.com/pg.php?page=index) judge.